# dynamically create radiobuttons and labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ok what I want to achieve is that it creates this automatically for each record I got back from my webservice.

```
<label for="ZAALID_1">Zaal 1</label>
                    <input id="ZAALID_1" type="radio" name="RESERVATIE.ZAALID" value="1" MSGCHECKED="~IF(CHKPROP(@RESERVATIE.ZAALID,'1'),CHECKED,)~" />
```

I am calling this webservice with an ajax call. There is nothing wrong with this call. I tested it with printing down the values.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "~SYSTEM.URL~~CAMPAIGN.URL~/SelligentMobile/Webservice/WebService.asmx/getReservaties",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'DATUM_BEGIN':'2012-05-09 10:10:36','DATUM_EINDE':'2012-05-09 12:10:45'}",
            success: function (response) {       
            var zalen = response.d;
              if (zalen.length > 0) {   
                       $.each(zalen, function (index, zaal) {
                    createRadioElement(zaal.zaalId);
                    createLabel(zaal.zaalNaam,zaal.zaalId);
                });
            } 
            }        
        });
```

So I think there is an mistake in CreateRadioElement and createLabel.
Here are these two functions.

```
function createRadioElement( id ) {
      var radioInput;
        try {
                var radioHtml = '<input id="ZAALID_' + id +  '" type="radio" name="RESERVATION.ZAALID" value="' + id + '" MSGCHECKED="~IF(CHKPROP(@RESERVATIE.ZAALID,' + 1 + '),CHECKED,)~ ';
                radioHtml += '/>';
            radioInput = document.createElement(radioHtml);
            } catch( err ) {
                radioInput = document.createElement('input');
                radioInput.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
                radioInput.setAttribute('name', 'RESERVATION.ZAALID');
            }
     return radioInput;
    }
    function createLabel(name,id) {
        var label;  
        var labelHTML = '<label for="ZAALID_' + id + '">'+ name +'</label>';

        label = document.createElement(labelHTML);
        return label;
    }
```

Now another thing that I want to do is that is places these radiobuttons inside the div with id=zaalField
here is the HTML of that div

```
<div id=ZaalField data-role="fieldcontain" class="knoppen_boven">
                <LABEL for=zaal>Zalen ter beschikking: </LABEL> 

                    //Here should go the radiobuttons and labels.

            </div>
```

Can anybody help ?

Kind regards

**---EDIT---**

```
 function getZalen()
    {
        var dateB = $("#DATUM_BEGIN").val();
        var dateE = $("#DATUM_EINDE").val();
        console.log(dateB);
        $.ajax({
            url: "~SYSTEM.URL~~CAMPAIGN.URL~/SelligentMobile/Webservice/WebService.asmx/getReservaties",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'DATUM_BEGIN':'2012-05-09 10:10:36','DATUM_EINDE':'2012-05-09 12:10:45'}",
            success: function (response) {       
            var zalen = response.d;
            alert(JSON.stringify(zalen));
              if (zalen.length > 0) {   
                    $.each(zalen, function (i, entity) {
                    $('ZaalField ').append(
                            $('<label />', { 'for': 'ZAALID_' + entity.zaalId, 'text': entity.zaalNaam }),
                            $('<input />', { 'id': 'ZAALID_' + entity.zaalId, 'type': 'radio', 'name': 'RESERVATION.ZAALID', 'value': entity.zaalId, 'MSGCHECKED': '~IF(CHKPROP(@RESERVATIE.ZAALID,' + 1 + '),CHECKED,)~ ' }), $('<br />'));
                });
            } 
            }        
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or what are you seeing?

Comment: in firebug I get this String contains an invalid character
label = document.createElement(labelHTML);

Comment: On the line before that, put "console.log(labelHTML, id, name)" and see what gets logged to the console. If any of them are null, it could be an issue.

Comment: No it gives this back <label for="ZAALID_2">Zaal 2</label> 2 Zaal 2

Comment: I get the same error as you. I have never created elements like you are doing it. Rather than passing an htmlstring to createElement, create the element and then set the attributes. That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = { "d": [{ "__type": "Reservatie", "zaalId": 2, "opmerking": null, "zaalNaam": "Zaal 2" }, { "__type": "Reservatie", "zaalId": 3, "opmerking": null, "zaalNaam": "Zaal 3"}] };

            //            $.ajax({
            //                url: "/SelligentMobile/Webservice/WebService.asmx/getReservaties",
            //                type: "POST", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //                dataType: "json", data: { 'DATUM_BEGIN': '2012-05-09 10:10:36', 'DATUM_EINDE': '2012-05-09 12:10:45' },
            //                success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.d, function (i, entity) {
                    $('body').append(
                            $('<label />', { 'for': 'ZAALID_' + entity.zaalId, 'text': entity.zaalNaam }),
                            $('<input />', { 'id': 'ZAALID_' + entity.zaalId, 'type': 'radio', 'name': 'RESERVATION.ZAALID', 'value': entity.zaalId, 'MSGCHECKED': '~IF(CHKPROP(@RESERVATIE.ZAALID,' + 1 + '),CHECKED,)~ ' }), $('<br />'));
                });
            }
            //                }
            //            });
        });
```

Comment: {"d":[{"__type":"Reservatie","zaalId":2,"opmerking":null,"zaalNaam":"Zaal 2"},{"__type":"Reservatie","zaalId":3,"opmerking":null,"zaalNaam":"Zaal 3"}]}

Comment: @Stef Geelen : now try this according to u r output.

Comment: here is the link according to u r output: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/z9WPZ/

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(data)); put this output here and check alert is coming in jquery ajax on success....

Comment: I edited my question with my function I got now. and the alert gives again {"d":[{"__type":"Reservatie","zaalId":2,"opmerking":null,"zaalNaam":"Zaal 2"},{"__type":"Reservatie","zaalId":3,"opmerking":null,"zaalNaam":"Zaal 3"}]}

Comment: same output i pasted there in http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/z9WPZ/ the output is coming... go to this link and check it again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11050/discussion-between-thulasiram-and-stef-geelen)

Answer (score 0):

```
function createLabel(id, name){
    var name = "Zaal 2";
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("for","RANDOM"+id);
    label.innerHTML = name;
    return label;
}

var label = createLabel(2, "Zaal 2");
$(document.body).append(label); //add it to the body, or to whatever else you want to add it to.
```

This code works for me, while the code you have written doesn't.

Comment: Ok I don't get any errors. But it's also not showing anything?

Comment: 2. In your code, you call the createLabel method, which returns a Label element. However, you don't store a reference to it, and you aren't adding it to the DOM. I have edited my answer for you.